# $f(x)\sim 1/x \implies (1+f(x))^x\to e$, but what family of functions maximizes the speed of convergence from below?

Tags: real-analysis, number-theory, convergence-divergence, prime-numbers, asymptotics

This problem is subordinate to finding out if $$\left(1+\frac{\log p_{n+1}}{p_n}\right)^{p_{n+1}/\log p_n},$$where $p_n$ is the $n$-th prime, never stabilizes above or below its limiting value, which is $e$. First of all, I tried using some bound  for the $n$-th prime, but even the tightest I found ([Dusart, 2010](http://arxiv.org/pdf/1002.0442.pdf)) didn't work.

So, here's the deal. Letting $x=p_{n+1}/\log p_n$ and $g(x)=\log p_{n+1}/p_n$ I considered the inequality $$\left(1+g(x)\right)^{x}<e\tag{$\star$}.$$ This and not the same in the other direction because even though initially $(\star)$ is most often false, and when it is true the difference in absolute value is smaller than when it is false, for $p_{n+1}/p_n$ small enough it is true (always for sufficiently large twin primes), and notoriously $\lim p_{n+1}/p_n =1$, hence I think it might change the trend, as $n\to\infty$; also because the classic $(1+1/x)^x$ approaches $e$ strictly from below. Indeed I noted that a successful strategy might be to find a family of functions $f$ maximizing the speed of convergence **from below**, since proving $g(x)<f(x)$ for large enough $x$ would result in solving my original problem. It is easy to see that $\frac{1}{x}$ is not what I'm looking for, since we trivially have $$\frac{\log p_{n+1}}{p_n}>\frac{\log p_n}{p_{n+1}}.$$ Soon I found what seems a good candidate, namely $$\left(1+\frac{\log(e+1/x)}{x\log\left(e-1/x^{5/3}\right)}\right)^x.$$ Below is its plot compared to that of $(1+1/x)^x$:[image]

For $x>x_P\approx 3.0812$ the function is below $e$. And, in fact, the difference between the two functions does seem to be always greater than $\frac{1}x$.

Well, have I found a function belonging to the maximizing family? How can I accelerate even more the convergence from below? Thank you.

Comment: This problem seems to be related to your "approximation of e"-problem. Your approach could lead to a proof that the approximation with the prime pairs indeed oscillates infinite many often. I tried concrete examples, and if the primes have size about $\large 10^{800}$, then there is still an oscillation!

Comment: @Peter Yeah. And, gosh, that's quite big, thanks! I think the oscillations can be finitely many only if the ratio of consecutive primes stops oscillating too much, which is something I doubt.

Comment: @Peter Any ideas regarding the inequality I've written in the update?

Comment: I believe I have a clue.

Comment: @YiannisGalidakis: I forgot if I had in mind something that excluded using your $f_n$, but it is certainly true they speed up the convergence from below as much as desired; thanks. Anyway, I stopped thinking about this problem a while after posting the question, simply noting that $(1+\log(x+2)/x)^{(x+2)/\log x}<e<(1+\log(x+\log x)/x)^{(x+\log x)/\log x}$ for large enough $x$;  the oscillation follows from the fact that both $p_{n+1}-p_n=246$ (see Yitang Zhang's theorem and its improvements)and $p_{n+1}-p_n>\log p_n$ occur infinitely often.